# Trying to build dia on Windows with MinGW

Tags: bash, makefile, automake, dia

I'm trying to build dia on my windows system with the MinGW toolkit.

What I did:

1. Downloaded [GTK all-in-one package](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php) and unpackged it to `C:\gtk` and did the setup described in the readme.
2. Downloaded [intltool-0.50.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-mingw/files/intltool/) and unpacked it into the `C:\gtk` dir
3. Added gtk's `bin` directory to `PATH` environment variable
4. Checked out dia into `C:\dia\`
5. Opened a command line with admin privileges
6. Opened a `bash` in `/c/dia/` and typed `autogen.sh`

The Script is running until it tries to execute the macro `IT_PROG_INTLTOOL(...)`

```
./configure: line 15572: syntax error near unexpected token `0.35.0'
./configure: line 15572: `IT_PROG_INTLTOOL(0.35.0)'
```

When I go to `configure.ac` and comment the line (I know I shouldn't do so, just for test purposes) `IT_PROG_INTLTOOL([0.35.0])` the next macro error comes up regarding `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`.

```
./configure: line 15577: syntax error near unexpected token `GMODULE,'
./configure: line 15577: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GMODULE, gmodule-2.0 gobject-2.0)'
```

As far as I can see, all these required libs (intltool, gmodule, pango, freetype, pkg-config, ...) are installed and can be found. But why do these macros not work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the configure script was regenerated and there were some errors while it was generated.

- You could try touch(1)'ing (however this is done on Windows...) files to avoid that the buildsystem tries to regenerate configure
- Make sure your autotools are all installed and that autoreconf does not spit out any warnings
- There are binary packages for dia on Windows available http://dia-installer.de/index.html.en

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware of the dia windows installer but I'm particularly interested in building it myself. Somehow the `*.m4` files containing the macros could not be found, so as a workaround I copied them by hand into a local `m4` directory which did the job. But I think this might not be the cleanest solution one could come up with. Building dia on windows is definitely not trivial...

Comment: aclocal has an -I flag, so instead of copying the m4 macros, you might as well specify the path were they are found.